# jqgrid + refresh grid with new data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, webmethod

I have a web app with a jqgrid which is populated with data using jquery ajax, which calls a webmethod. The jqgrid is refreshed every 5 seconds to poll data. what i would like to do is get new data that is added to the table every 5 seconds.

So i thought i would modify my webmethod to get data in batches of 20, starting from the last ID read. What i thought is in the webmethod i would do a counter, firstRecordID, lastRecordIDRead variables, if counter = 0 i would get the first record ID and store it in firstRecordID, if counter is larger than 0 than firstRecordID would be the lastRecordIDRead (firstRecordID + 20). So if the first ID in database is 906, on the first poll it would get records from 906 to 925, then in second poll it will get from 926 + 20 other records and continue like this.

When this method is used in a console app as an example it worked fine, however i cant understand how should i go to implement this when using a webservice, since a webservice is stateless i dont know how i should implement the counter variable etc. Any idea please? Or maybe a solution which is better?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Session variable to track things, but my recommendation would be having the grid manage this counter itself.

To have the grid post up an extra parameter containing the value of the id it is on is fairly simple.  You can pass an extra value up via the

```
postData: { KeyName: KeyValue},
```

In the instance where you are calling (I'm assuming via a timer event) to refresh the grid just add where you would update this parameter when asking the grid to refresh.

Ex:

```
$('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { KeyName: KeyValue} }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

On the controller side (I'm going to show C# code but the fundamentals are the same) you would evaluate this extra value to change what data you return to the jqGrid as per your requirements.

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters, string KeyName)
        {
          //logic to change dataset being returned based on KeyName value.
          ...
```

Comment: so in order to get the value of KeyValue i would do as Raman suggested? store the value from the webmethod on success to a hidden field, and then pass it using postData like the following:postData: {
            'KeyName': function () {

                return $("txtRecordID").val();
            }
        },

Comment: There would be no need to use a hidden field, it can be easily stored in jqGrid.  If you want to retrieve it you can simply access it via: `$('#gridName').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData.KeyName')`

Comment: May I ask why you want to retrieve it though? When you call the refresh of the grid you could increment the value at that point. Ex `$('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { KeyName: KeyValue + intValue} }).trigger('reloadGrid');`

Comment: ah ok thanks, however first time the grid is loaded on document load the postdata parameter will be null any idea how should i handle this

Comment: Yes, just set it as part of your grid setup to 0.

Comment: great thanks it worked! you have been of great help! what i haven't thought of is that when jqGrid is reloaded the records previous polled will be removed and grid will be filled with new data instead of having the newly records added to the previously added one...so now i have to options, either make the query return all data with every grid reload including the new ones...or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Do you mean when the jqGrid is reloaded or the page is reloaded?

Comment: when jqGrid is reloaded. basically on page load i'm passing a value of 906....and retrieve the first 20 records 906-926, then after 5 seconds, i refresh the grid and get another 20 records from 926 onward...

Comment: Why pass in a value that is tied to the database in some manner, why not pass in 20, then increment your post value by 20. When you get to the end of the records you could pass down a bool in userData to tell the value to reset.

Comment: the reason of passing a value tied to the database, is because when i get the first batch of 20 records, with the next batch i would need to know the record ID from where to start again...so if the first batch started from 906 and ended at 926, when polling the second batch i have to start from 926 and not from 906. thus i have to pass in the last record id of the previous call. Should i paste in some code maybe?

Comment: I guess I was thinking that you would want to decouple that kind of action and you would just be passing in a value of 20 that would then say to your controller, get the page of records after skipping 20, then the next time it would say get the page of records after skipping 40.  Either way would work, just passing in the record number couples your client side to your server side. If that isn't an issue go for it.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes it has been very helpful, i'm still trying to figure it out however. I got your point of skipping 20 and next increment which each call and modified my linq to sql query to use skip and take. however it's not working, currently it would skip 20, and then just keep getting the next 20 with every refresh. on grid setup postdata value is set to 0, then on refresh i have set up value to 20. and in the controller i'm doing takeValue = postdatavalue and skipValue= postDataValue +20. however it fails since everytime the postData is being 10. how can i increment it before doing the call?

Comment: I wrote it above in a comment where you increment the value before triggering the reload.

Comment: yes however for some reason var testVal = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData.KeyName'); returns null

Comment: When you assign the testVal to yes however for some reason `var testVal = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData')` does that object contain the value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right. I guess what you can do is fetch the IDs also in the data and keep in the hidden column in the jqGrid. Have one more hidden control in you page as keep its initial value as 0. In your service call send value in the hidden control as a parameter.

On server side check if the value is 0 fetch the first 20 rows and send back. For example you fetch rows from 906 to 925 and send back. On success of the ajax call. Save 925 in hidden control. So now onward when second call will happen it will send value of hidden control that will be 925 now and then on server side you can fetch rows from 926 to 945. Again store 945 in hidden control, so third time value sent will be 945. This way you can save the last Id in every service call and send that id as parameter and fetch next rows.